# Multi-level tag existence check in web scraping - improving readability in python

Tags: python, error-handling, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a scraper running through many pages built from the same template. Each page holds some information regarding a specific item. In the optimistic case, I want to get all available data, for simplicity let's say it means name, price, and description.

Pages are structured as follows:

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1>Product name</h1>
  <table id="properties">
    <tbody>
      <tr id="manufacturer-row">
        <th>Manufacturer</th>
        <td>Some-Mark</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p>Full description of the product</p>
</div>
```

Conditions that apply to this case:

1. Tags are nested so that I need to test for existence of each level,
2. Some pages will miss some data - empty column in a table is just as possible as missing table,
3. Some pages will have no content at all,
4. Empty text in tag is a valid value, but missing tag must be logged,
5. Missing data is not an exceptional situation.

In effect, I test check the presence of each piece of information, which leads to pretty hardly readable code:

```
content = soup.select_one("#content")
if content:
    product_name_tag = content.select_one("h1")
    if product_name_tag:
        name = product_name_tag.text
    else:
        log("Product name tag not found")

    table = content.select_one("table")
    if table:
        manufacturer_tag = table.select_one("#manufacturer-row > td")
        if manufacturer_tag:
            manufacturer = manufacturer_tag.text
        else:
            log("Manufacturer tag not found")
    else:
        log("Table not found")
else:
    log("Tag '#content' not found")

return (
    name if name in locals() else None,
    manufacturer if manufacturer in locals() else None
)
```

In actual application the code is harder to read as properties I'm looking for are often more nested and I need to check existence of each tag before extracting its text. I was wondering if there is any neat way to handle this problem in terms of code readability and conciseness? My ideas:

**Creating a function to extract tag's text if tag exists** - would save few lines, but in real application I must use regexes to extract some phrases from text, so a single function would not be enough.

**Creating a wrapper** to log missing pieces if None was returned rather than under 'else' code - for improved readability.

**Putting extraction of each piece of data to separate function,** like _get_content_if_available, _get_name_if_available

Neither of those solutions seems to be good and concise enough, so I'd like to ask you for ideas.

I am also wondering if my way of initializing variables only if some conditions are met and then checking whether a variable exists in current context is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

All depends how do you want to structure your code. My suggestion is use `ChainMap` from `collections`. With `ChainMap` you can specify default values for your tags/keys and just parse the values that aren't missing. That way you will don't have if/else cluttered along your codebase:

```
data = """<div id="content">
  <h1>Product name</h1>
  <table id="properties">
    <tbody>
      <tr id="manufacturer-row">
        <th>Manufacturer</th>
        <td>Some-Mark</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p>Full description of the product</p>
</div>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import ChainMap

def my_parse(soup):
    def is_value_missing(k, v):
        if v is None:
            print(f'Value "{k}" is missing!') # or log it!
        return v is None

    d = {}
    d['product_name_tag'] = soup.select_one("h1")
    d['manufacturer_tag'] = soup.select_one("#manufacturer-row td")
    d['description'] = soup.select_one("p")
    d['other value'] = soup.select_one("nav")   # this is missing!
    return {k:v.text for k, v in d.items() if is_value_missing(k, v) == False}

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
c = ChainMap(my_parse(soup), {'product_name_tag': '-default name tag-',
             'manufacturer_tag': '-default manufacturer tag-',
             'description': '-default description-',
             'other value': '-default other value-',
             })

print("Product name = ", c['product_name_tag'])
print("Other value = ", c['other value'])
```

This will print:

```
Value "other value" is missing!
Product name =  Product name
Other value =  -default other value-
```